# Flutter save a whole website for future rendering

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I am developing an application in flutter for mobile devices (android and ios) and need to save the graphical appearance of a site at a given instant of time. What is the best way to achieve this?

- If I save the html code to display it in a webview I have display problems due to local or remote css/js files;
- If I try to take the screenshot I have to load it into a webview first and in any way it is done only of the part visible on the screen and not of the internal site (via screenshot library);
  It would also be convenient to save it as a pdf but I haven't found any library to do that.

Comment: Save the state of everything relevant to your display and store it in persistent storage then just recreate the display from the state.

Comment: I need to store the website in background (also if app is closed) with background task. I great idea could be store the website view as pdf, also for storage performance, but there isn't any packgage to do so.

Comment: Why do you want to store it as pdf? Is there an issue with what I proposed?

Comment: how can I save the state?

Comment: Store the variables that make up the state in some kind of persistent storage(e.g. SharePreferences, some database, or just a file). You could make a class that represents the state and write a function to serialize the class before writing to storage to make it cleaner.

Comment: ok but how i can i save a webview?

Comment: Are you asking how to save a webview that is embedded in a Flutter Web application?

Comment: How to save a webview that is embedded in a Flutter mobile (iOS e ANdroid) Application